# How Can i solved this error:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '30' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I am facing an issue when inserting values from a form into my mysql -`table item_image`- with the -`lastInsertId()`-

**Here is my db**

```
item table
id(auto increment,Primary key)
item_name (varchar)
item_description (tinytext)
item_price(varchar)
item_date(date)

item_image
itemId(PRIMARY KEY),
small_image(varchar),
big_image(varchar)
```

HERE IS MY FORM

```
<form method="post" action="?<?php echo $action;?>">
<p>
<label for="item_name">Name of Article :</label>
<input type="text" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="item_description">Short Description:</label>
<textarea id="item_description" name="item_description" rows="3" cols="40" value=""></textarea>
 </p>

<p>
<label for="">Item small Image :</label>
<input type="text" id="small_image" name="addimages[]" value="" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="">Item small Image:</label>
<input type="text" id="big_image" name="addimages[]" value="" />
</p>

<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="<?php echo $button;?>" />
</div>
```

**AND DOWN HERE WE HAVE THE PHP CODE**

```
if (isset($_GET['addform'])) {
$item_name = trim($_POST['item_name']);
$item_description = trim($_POST['item_description']);
$item_price = trim($_POST['item_price']);

 try {

$sql = 'INSERT INTO items SET 
        item_name = :item_name,
        item_description = :item_description,
        item_price = :item_price,
        item_date= CURDATE()';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':item_name', $item_name);
$stmt->bindValue(':item_description', $item_description);
$stmt->bindValue(':item_price', $item_price);
$stmt->execute();
 } 
  catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo "Something went wrong".$e->getMessage();
 }

$itemId = $pdo->lastInsertId(); 

  if (isset($_POST['addimages'])) {

    $add_images = $_POST['addimages'];

    try {
      $sql ='INSERT INTO item_image SET
              itemId = :itemId,
             small_image = :small_image,
             big_image = :big_image';
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
         foreach ($add_images as $add_image) {
           $stmt->bindValue(':itemId', $itemId);
           $stmt->bindValue(':small_image', $add_image[0]);
           $stmt->bindValue(':big_image', $add_image[1]);
           $stmt->execute();
         }
    }   
      catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "Sth got wrong with the query".$e->getMessage();
    }
  }
```

The issue i am having is : All the values got insert in items table, but for the item_image table...i am having this error :

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '30' for key 'PRIMARY`'

I am having searching, but cannot find the issue..my foreach loop seems to be correct..

I am trying to is to do is to: insert the `lastInsertId()` value and `addimages array values` into my **item_image** table

Can sombody help out..Thanks.

Comment: Your item_image.itemId is a primary key which is basically an unique index. What you want is a foreign key (indexed value) to link the images to the corresponding item entities. You should dig a bit into relational databasemodels and constraints which will give you a better understanding in how to create a good database structure (there is enough on google).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set a unique index for `itemId` column in `item_image` table, but according to the info you've provided, your items can have multiple images, therefore multiple `itemId` columns in `item_image` table can have the same value (referencing to the "parent" image's id), and unique index should not be used there. Use normal index for that column.

Comment: you are saying i should put the ItemId-to auto increment?

Comment: If `itemId` references the id from items table (and it seems so), then NO. Auto-increment column is automatically a primary key, which will also deny having multiple columns with the same value. Your `itemId` in images table references the item that images belong to, so just use regular index (not unique, not primary key, just 'index' so MySQL can look them up faster)

Answer (score 0):

The message means you are doing another insert with the same combination of columns. If you are inserting records, insert new records into table. Not same records.

And try to put auto increment on your itemId.